# Get Favicon from theme assets to HTML in Sylius

Tags: html, path, sylius, theming

I am trying to get the favicon image inside the `head` in a Sylius theme. The favicon is located inside the Sylius Bootstrap theme / `assets`. Now, I can normally use those assets inside a `CSS` file, but I would somehow need to import it inside the `layout.html.twig`. It does not work whatever path I give it, and I'm wondering is it even possible. What am I doing wrong here..?

I tried to do it like this and many other ways:

```
<link rel="apple-icon" sizes="180x180" href="url(/build_dev/bootstrap-theme/images/apple-icon-180x180.png)">
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, that I understand your question correct.
But, I think that can  help you

1. you have to check filename in folder `<kernel.root_path>/public/build_dev/bootstrap-theme/images/apple-icon-180x180.png`
2. use special twig function for including static files

```
<img src="{{ asset('bootstrap-theme/images/apple-icon-180x180.png', 'bootstra-theme') }}" alt="Symfony!" />
```

3. depends on env (prod|dev) you can set path `build_dev` or `build`. See docs https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#assets